# Hyperlink to new page not opening with passed variable

Tags: php, html

I have a form which have two input named uin and order date these two field fetch the data from a table.There is one button (Generate) which navigates to new page viewstationerypdf.php  carrying the value selected in these two field.When i click on this button it does not react it is not taking me into new page .Data is fetching in both the input field .My code is-

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label> UIN<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="uin" id="uin">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT uin from  tblstationerystock group by uin order by uin asc";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $cnt=1;
    if($query->rowCount() > 0)
    {
    foreach($results as $result)
    {  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>">
      <?php echo htmlentities($result->uin);?>
    </option>
    <?php }} ?>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label> ORDER DATE<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <select class="form-control" name="orderdate" id="orderdate" value="" ;>

  </select>
</div>

<button><a href="stationerypdf.php?uin=<?php echo $_POST[uin];?> & orderdate= <?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> target="popup"  onclick="window.open('stationerypdf.php?uin=<?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> & orderdate= <?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?> ,'popup','height=600,width=900 top=15 left=300,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no'); return false;" > GENERATE</button></a>
```

Comment: this link is working on the same page? if yes than just add <a target="_blank">

Comment: @FullStop not working

Comment: By the way, are you expecting the link to change when the user changes the dropdown? Because that will not happen without JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid

Style the anchor instead of wrapping it in a button and make sure your do not have spaces in the href and have correct commas in the parameters

Also you had a missing " in the href

This one will return a falsy "!w" if there is no popup blocker

```css
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<a href="stationerypdf.php?uin=<?php echo $_POST[uin];?>&orderdate=<?php echo $_POST[orderdate];?>" 
target="popup" class="button" 
onclick="var w=window.open(this.href,'popup','height=600,width=900,top=15,left=300'); return !w;">GENERATE</a>
```

Do note that you are inviting XSS with your code since if I can post a uin of
`" onclick="location='https://hackersite.com'"`
the user will get that in the page.

https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: it is not working The url it generated  showing error

Comment: /localhost/sms/admin/stationerypdf.php?uin=<br%20/><b>Warning</b>:%20%20Use%20of%20undefined%20constant.........